# How do I increase the font size based on the window width?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-size

I am creating a web-based app that will be displayed on television and other large monitors. I am wanting a quick and easy way to increase the font size to fit the window size. The text is dynamic.

Any help is greatly appreciated. ;)

Answer (score 16):

If you're interested in / able to use **CSS3** then there is a pure CSS solution - **media queries** >> http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

So for example, the CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 800px) { ... }
```

...allows you to specify different styles for the page when displayed on a 800px screen or greater. Obviously you can vary this as you like - powerful stuff

You may also want to consider the prewritten javascript at the end of this link ...
http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/ResolutionLayout/#

Comment: Does this work when the window is resized or does it only check dimensions upon loading the document...?

Answer (score 13):

OK - for starters, you should use Ems for as many measurements as you can in your UI. At the very least, size all of your text elements with Ems (rather than pixels or %'s). If possible, setting the width of layout blocks in Ems will help the app scale in proportion, too. If you can set all your dimensions in Ems, your entire app will be visually scalable.

The key to Ems is that they're sized relative to the font size of their parent element - which means you can adjust the size of all the text in proportion, by adjusting the font-size of the body element (since everything is relative to the body).

The last step is to use a piece of javascript to detect the width of the viewport, and set the font-size of the body accordingly. Depending on how fine-grained you want to control the scale, you can either use classes on the body element to set up a set of pre-defined values, or directly manipulate the font-size itself. I'd tend to use pre-determined sizes if possible to make testing easier.

I'd use a javascript library to make the detection of the viewport width easier - it's notoriously different in different browsers. With jQuery, the code could look like:

```
$(function(){
  var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();

  if (viewPortWidth > 1900) {$('body').addClass('extraWide')}
  else if (viewPortWidth > 1400) {$('body').addClass('wide')}
  else if (viewPortWidth > 1000) {$('body').addClass('standard')}
  else if (viewPortWidth > 700) {$('body').addClass('narrow')}
  else {$('body').addClass('extraNarrow')}

});
```

And the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

  body {font-size:62.5%;}  /* Set the size of 1em to 10px in all browsers */

  body.extraWide {font-size:85%;}
  body.wide {font-size:75%;}

  body.narrow {font-size:50%;}
  body.extraNarrow {font-size:40%;}

</style>
```

Those values can be tweaked however you like, of course, and you can set up as many divisions as you want. This is very much a quick-and-dirty solution, but should do the trick.

*A note* - the javascript code shown will only set the scale once when the page is loaded - it won't adjust it when you change the size of your window. That's a possible addition, but there are bigger considerations before heading down that track. Personally, I'd even think about setting the scale value in a cookie, to keep the user's experience consistent throughout their session, rather than rescaling on every page load.

Comment: I hope the downvotes against this answer are due to there being better, more modern solutions to this problem now. That's not to say this answer is _wrong_, but media queries should be the first thing to try to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 3):

I know this in quite an old question, but I will be answering anyways due to this being a question that could be searched upon a lot.

There is actually another approach other than Media Queries which is also pure CSS:

---

**Viewport units:** `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax`.

These are length units representing 1% of the viewport size for viewport width (vw), height (vh), the smaller of the two (vmin), or the larger of the two (vmax).

So for example you could use:

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-size:5vmin;
}
```

This sets the font-size of the entire document to 5% of the smallest viewport size (the width or the height). So for instance on an iPad (1024 x 768 px) the `font-size` will be **38,4 px** *(5% of 768 px because this is the smallest size of either viewport sizes)*.

**Browser compatibility:** https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: This is great and all. Had to learn the hard way today (refactoring) that ems still are better if you want to use a component with text in different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

A better version (for me) of the solution provided by japanFour:

```
$(document).ready(scaleFont);
$(window).resize(scaleFont);


function scaleFont() {

  var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();

  if (viewPortWidth >= 1900) {$('body').attr('class','extraWide');}
  else if (viewPortWidth >= 1400) {$('body').attr('class','wide');}
  else if (viewPortWidth >= 1000) {$('body').attr('class','');}
  else if (viewPortWidth >= 700) {$('body').attr('class','narrow');}
  else {$('body').attr('class','extraNarrow');}
}
```

So it resizes only if window is resized (avoiding `setTimout`), and you give `body` only the exact class it needs

Answer (score 0):

Beejamin's answer worked as expected, I added a set timeout so it would scale in real time. It doesn't reverse scale though.

```
$(document).ready(function() {scaleFont();});

    function scaleFont() {

      var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();

      if (viewPortWidth > 1900) {$('body').addClass('extraWide')}
      else if (viewPortWidth > 1400) {$('body').addClass('wide')}
      else if (viewPortWidth > 1000) {$('body').addClass('standard')}
      else if (viewPortWidth > 700) {$('body').addClass('narrow')}
      else {$('body').addClass('extraNarrow')}

      setTimeout(scaleFont, 100); 
    }
```

**EDIT: SOLVED REVERSE EFFECT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {scaleFont();});

    function scaleFont() {

      var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();

      if (viewPortWidth >= 1900) {$('body').addClass('extraWide').removeClass('wide, standard, narrow, extraNarrow')}
      else if (viewPortWidth >= 1400) {$('body').addClass('wide').removeClass('extraWide, standard, narrow, extraNarrow')}
      else if (viewPortWidth >= 1000) {$('body').addClass('standard').removeClass('extraWide, wide, narrow, extraNarrow')}
      else if (viewPortWidth >= 700) {$('body').addClass('narrow').removeClass('extraWide, standard, wide, extraNarrow')}
      else {$('body').addClass('extraNarrow').removeClass('extraWide, standard, wide, narrow')}


      setTimeout(scaleFont, 100); 
    }
```

Comment: a timeout for such an operation is an overkill. why don't you use the resize event of window? that way the code works once when browser is resized.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my approach (with removing actual classes + Drupal 7 jQuery):

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {


var bodyClassArr = new Array('extraWide', 'wide', 'normal', 'narrow', 'extraNarrow', 'mobile');

function setBodyClass(){
  // remove previous classes
  for(x in bodyClassArr){
      if($('body').hasClass(bodyClassArr[x])){ $('body').removeClass(bodyClassArr[x]); }
  }
  var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();
  if (viewPortWidth > 1900) { $('body').addClass('extraWide'); }
  else if (viewPortWidth > 1400) { $('body').addClass('wide'); }
  else if (viewPortWidth > 1000) { $('body').addClass('normal'); }
  else if (viewPortWidth > 700) { $('body').addClass('narrow'); }
  else if (viewPortWidth < 700) { $('body').addClass('mobile'); }
  else { $('body').addClass('normal'); }
};
setBodyClass();

$(window).resize(function() { setBodyClass(); });

}); // jquery end
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with the following code?  While I agree media queries are very useful, I wanted to continuously scale the font-size of certain elements of my page as the window either grew or shrunk. This code seems much simpler than the other jquery solutions of establishing class constants based on viewport pixel width:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var setFontSize = function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    var fontSize = Math.sqrt(viewportWidth/250);
    $('.myElement').css('font-size',fontSize+'em');
  };

  $(window).resize(function() {
    setFontSize();
  });

  setFontSize();

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Heres a simpler and no-jquery solution:

```
onresize=onload=function(){document.body.style.fontSize=window.innerWidth+"px"}
```

Comment: This is a GOOD code. I dont get why they downvote. Anyway, I try to do something like `onresize=onload=function(){document.getElementById("post").style.fontSize=document.getElementById("icon").width+"px"};` where `post` is the id of a button and `icon` a div. I try to base the size of the button's letters to a div. Does not work. Any Advise?