# problem with font-size using html and css

Tags: html, css, menu, screen-resolution, font-size

when i built my first all html/css website i used clickable images as a menu and every image and div scaled in % so it would adapt extremely well to all monitors and browsers, and it did.

now on a new project i wanted to do the website menu using a background image for the whole page (with the menu buttons on it but with no text) and then hyperlinked text on top of the image so it would look like a proper menu.

so i though, well if i just put the font-size in % it will probably scale perfectly as the size of the display part of the browser window increases or decreases, it worked so perfectly with everything else so why shouldn't it work now...

i've done it and it doesn't work, i don't know where in hell the thing get it's percentages from, if i set 100% font size in a div that has 2% or 3% the size of the page the text depending on the resolution will be too large or too small.

i know how i can make the things scalable according to the browser window, but how i can make text size scalable according to that thing or the browser window itself?

a response telling how to do this using only css and html it's better for me, i know a bit of scripting but i don't like to mix the display part with the script part so if you anybody knows how to make this using only html/css i will continue to use clickable images and percentages or pixels for the whole thing.

thank you.

Comment: There's no way to make font-sizes relative to window/container size in browsers using plain CSS. It's just not supported. You can use javascript to do the calculations for you, though, and set a global base font size from which you set relative sizes on everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution to this problem would be to use a fluid / responsive CSS framework, and then use **media queries** to adjust the font size depending on the width of the browser to make sure it looks great at ever possible width.

A few examples would be:

1140 grid (http://cssgrid.net/)

Skeleton (http://www.getskeleton.com/)

or one I'm currently working (https://github.com/gogogarrett/Muscle)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`font-size` doesn't work that way.

`font-size` is a size relative to the font-size of its parent element.

In CSS, you cannot resize fonts according to the window width. However, this is possible to calculate [in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146395/how-to-increase-font-size-based-on-window-width).

Comment: font-size isn't completely relative to the parent element, if it were, my problem would be solved. if you do a little testing you will figure that out.

Comment: @wxiir I think you misunderstood what I said. It's not relative to the size of the parent element, it's relative to the **font size** of the parent element.

Comment: that's right i really didn't understanded what you said, i'm sorry. but anyway, if i understanded now it's still wrong. if the text or the parent element have an absolute font-size and the other has a relative font-size, the absolute will prevail, if both have absolute font-sizes, the parent element font-size will prevail and if both have relative font sizes there probably is a default font size determined by the browser or some crap and so the font will resize a bit depending on the browser