# Resize font size of h1 when browser resolution is below 1260px

Tags: css

I'm stuck, I am designing a webpage on resolution 1266px.
I want it to fit on 1024px because 13% of the people are still using that resolution.
So I thought I could change the fontsize of my h1 and my nav_items.

So that they will fit, if the resolution drops below 1260 else I want them to stay at the fixed px given to them.

This is what I got:

```
header {
  width:100%;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #000;
}
header h1 { /* TAVERNE DE STADSPOORT */
  font-size: 40px;
  float:left;
  color:white;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; /* top, left, bottom, right*/ 
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px; /* top, right, bottom, right*/
}
header ul {
  float: right; 
  width: 680px;
  padding: 20px; 0px; 0px; 0px; /* top, left, bottom, right*/
}
.nav_items li {
  display:inline;
  font-size:22px;
  margin: 0px 4px 0px 4px; /* top, left, bottom, right (outside) */ 
  padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px; /* top, left, bottom, right*/ 
}
```

```
<div id="logo">
<h1 class="nav_items"><a href="index.html">Taverne De Stadspoort</a></h1>
</div>
<nav id="top">
    <ul class="nav_items">
        <li><a href="/">Menukaart</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Suggesties</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Onze wijnen</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Ligging/contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Gastenboek</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Maybe I did something wrong, and I could resolve this problem a other way.
Or should I use jquery instead for archieving this? since I am not familair with that
an other solution would be great.

i added this: thx all

```
@media all and (max-width: 1259px) { h1 { font-size: 25px; } }
@media all and (min-width: 1260px) { h1 { font-size: 40px; } } 
/* http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ */
```

Comment: Do you have a media query that adjusts the size? Or if you don't know what a media query is, I can introduce it in an answer.

Comment: Or, look at other, duplicate questions on the subject... [How to increase font size based on window width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146395/how-to-increase-font-size-based-on-window-width)

Comment: Just got a quick glimpse of media query, sinds i din't really know what is was. I dit not set anything yet. How can this help me? i'll continue reading more about it. Sinds i do not understand yet how i can use this –

Comment: Thx for the help and pointing me out to media queries, i dit not know about that yet.

Comment: If it is solved, accept an answer. No need to add it to the question.

Comment: thx, found it, din't see it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g

```
@media all and (min-width: 1266px) {

    h1 {
      font: (large-size)px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1265px) {

    h1 {
      font: (smaller-size)px;
    }
}
```

Comment: LukaD I couldn't figure out why it was looking like that. Had I screwed up when highlighting the code or did I add/remove something I shouldn't have!?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries). They let you specify styles for specific screen resolutions (an much more).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#fit').resizable({
    resize: function( event, ui ) {

        divWidth = ui.size.width/(len*9);
        divHeight = ui.size.height / (len *2.2);

        abc = divWidth;
        if (divWidth < divHeight) { 
          abc = divWidth; 
        } else {
            abc = divHeight
        }

        ui.element.css({'font-size': abc +'em'});
        console.log(abc);

    }
});
```