# Tweaking performance of elegant solution to text resize for fluid/responsive designs?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, responsive-design, media-queries

I find the following JS solution to having text resize based on viewport size quite elegant:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10295733/1318135

```
onresize=onload=function(){document.body.style.fontSize=window.innerWidth+"px"}
```

However, there are 2 issues:

1. It relies on the viewport being resized.  I'd like to trigger it when the page is first loaded as well, but am a newb at JS.
2. My page is coded entirely using em values; this uses px.  How can I use this to adjust the **default em size only** which will then automatically trickle down to every other element on the page?

http://jsfiddle.net/hFNc7/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See other answer (or put http://jsfiddle.net/cjzEK/1/ on the bottom of your page)
2. em is not a size on its own. It's a percentage written differently. The only way em works for you is because there is 1 base font-size that is set in the browser(or also likely a reset stylesheet). The usual base size of fonts in browsers is 16px. So what this solution does is changing the base size by adding it to the body(adding it to the html might be even better).

e.g. `p{font-size:1em;}` without any reset done will be 16px. 1.5em will be 24px.

Comment: Gueze Based on the code of the question, I try to do something like `onresize=onload=function(){document.getElementById("post").style.fontSize=document.getElementById("icon").width+"px"};` where `post` is the id of a button and `icon` a div. I try to base the size of the button's letters to a div. Does not work. Any Advise? Thanks

Comment: Width is not an available property on divs. Try `docum‌​ent.getElementById("icon").clientWidth` to get the real rendered width of an element, including padding. You can read about it, and more, on MDN. If you need more help you should open a new topic(after searching for related ones)

Comment: Geuze Works fine, but for some reason the size of the text is huge. Anyway i will keep searching. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You need to run that code in the `body`'s `load` event. Easiest way to do so is setting it directy through its `onload` attribute:

```
<body onload="var f = function () { document.body.style.fontSize = 0.2 * window.innerWidth + 'px'; }; window.onresize = f; f();">
```

What it does:

1. Creates a function, that is able to set the font size dynamically.
2. Sets the function as `resize` event listener.
3. Execute the function instantly.

PS: There are more elegant ways to write this, but since your new, it might be better to start with an easier notation.

Comment: I just forgot to mention, that you can change `px` to `em` if you like. But I recommend you to set that one default size absolutely. Else you'd depend on the user's browser settings.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'll likely use this solution, but I'm curious what the more elegant ones you mention are.

Comment: More elegant would be not writing it in the html file but in a separate JavaScript file.

Comment: Hmm... I'd like to post some lines of code here... Well, just get it from http://pastebin.com/LeDv6yhH

Comment: @ReneGeuze: That code just works in case `document.body` already exists. So in case it's above the HTML notation of the `body` tag, it might run into problems!

Comment: @ReneGeuze is that not a different solution? It looks like different syntax.

Comment: My code works as long as you put the script at the end of the body. Where I actually always put my script unless there is a special requirement. Should have noted that.

Comment: The original solution here is not functioning correctly for me.

Comment: Actually neither @LarsKnickrehm solution is functioning for me at the moment.  It seems not to recognize 'var' as JS for some reason?

Comment: @user1318135: Do you mean the original answer or my latter comment?

Comment: Please, provide a test file, so I can reproduce it. I tested the above code before posting...