# auto-resize buttons for responsive design

Tags: css, resize, responsive-design

Is there a way to have buttons that auto-resize to fit its container , in order to have responsive design?

It would be even better I think If there is an approach , not based on media queries (= less code)

Hope the image helps you.  Here is the CSS for the button

```
.formButtonfront {
 width: auto;
border:1px solid gray;
border-radius:7%;
float:right;
font-size:0.875;
 }
```

The browser is Chrome in a laptop, just sized down

I want the grey button (placed after the image) to fit the white container

Thanks in advance

PS About the float : I have a `clear:both;` in the footer. Also even If I remove the float, the result is the same.

**UPDATE**
Here 's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/fg7VL/11/)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us the CSS for the parent and the html in order to answer you more accurately?

Comment: @thomasstephn I updated my question, adding a fiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you don't need `display: block` or `float: none`, but a `max-width`

```
.formButtonfront {
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-radius:7%;
  font-size:0.875;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100px; // only for IE8
  max-width: 100%;
 }
```

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fg7VL/12/) (I reduce the size of the content to see how it looks)

Comment: Thanks. One last thing : `max-width` is not supported by IE<8 if I remember correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not really an IE8 issue since IE8 does support the ```max-width``` attribute but only when given a defined width first. So try something like ```width: 100%; max-width: 25em;``` . I edited my answer

Comment: Your anser is good, but `word-wrap` is not a good idea aesthetically, to be honest. Breaks words out of control. I found this`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798926/tweaking-performance-of-elegant-solution-to-text-resize-for-fluid-responsive-des` and I try to do something like `onresize=onload=function(){document.getElementById("button").style.fontSize=document.getElementsByClassName("container").innerWidth+"px"};` combined with `width:auto` but, cannot get it to work...

Comment: The box is resizing which was your question, after that it's a design decision I agree. Either word wrap, small font or text-overflow: ellipsis

Answer (score 2):

make `float: none` and `display: block` for that button.

It will make button as container and fit the parent box.

I think it will help you.

Comment: Thanks fot the anser, but sorry, this not helping at all. The button is still outside the container

Comment: 1. Remove the height property on the white box.
2. Maybe your text on the button looks much bigger than width of container? Try `word-wrap: break-word` and `width: 100%` please.

Comment: `word-wrap` helps a little. But, `width:100%` creates a huge button when the browser is not sized down. And If I put `width:40%` the button is not big when the browser is sized down, but the letters are the one above the other... Anyway, I added a link to my question...

Answer (score 1):

```css
button{
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  Button
</button>
```