# HTML/CSS - change button size with browser

Tags: html, css

guys, can't understand how it works.

```
.butts {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-left: 40px;

}
.butt {
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Want to change button size with resizing the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Comment: Shoud I hardcode for every resolution, yes?

Comment: @Chainsaw No, only trigger when you want to change something. Start from mobile first.

Comment: @Chainsaw write 3-4 media queries, thats usually enough. There you only write what is changed. Be pragmatic when using them. Write in the way so that one size is enough till next media query and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[auto-resize buttons for responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918085/auto-resize-buttons-for-responsive-design)
you can refer to this answer for your issue as you can set the max-width:100% for the whichever button to resize in your browser.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, please do not post link only answers. I know you don't have enough rep to comment, but if you do choose to answer, please include the solution in the answer - not a link. In this particular case, I would consider writing your own answer - or not answer since this topic is already covered on Stack Overflow (your link, for instance)

Comment: i will keep these things in mind from next time while answering

Answer (score 2):

put for properties "padding" in button class.
Or
Change height and width button.

Comment: This does not answer the question.