# Responsive image and text at same time

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is there a way to make text on the right side, scale as the image on the left side at same time. When I try to resize browser text height goes outside. I try to do this with media queries but it doesn't work. Also I don't want to use height on element. Is this possible? Here is the jsfiddle:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/mbole87/a9zstjzb/1/]
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146395/how-do-i-increase-the-font-size-based-on-the-window-width

Comment: @mbole87 what you ask is not clear. do you mean the font size or the size of the box containing text??

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "vw" value in CSS? Along with some CSS for your image too of course...

```
.some-class{
    font-size: 2vw
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not well supported in browser.

Comment: No, buts it's the only real way you'll be able to provide truly responsive text. Downside is that it's also dependant on the viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to add min and max height attributes to the boxes.

```
min-height: ___;
max-height: ___;
overflow: hidden;
```

and then add Overflow: hidden, so therefore if you put too much text into the box it is going to hide it to prevent it from going outside..